# XCode TestPlan: specify which configuration to use from command line

Tags: xcode, xctestplan

I have a few configurations in my XCode project's test plan, by default, executing UI tests will execute all configurations, but for some requirement I need to exclude one or two based on certain conditions on CI, I found that I can specify what scheme or test plan to execute, but is there a way to specify what test plan configurations to include or exclude, from command line? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the configurations like this:

```
$> xcodebuild test -workspace <path> 
                   -scheme <name> 
                   -destination <specifier>
                   -testPlan <name>
                   -only-test-configuration <configuration1> 
                   -only-test-configuration <configuration2>
                   ...
```

Or skip configurations like this:

```
$> xcodebuild test -workspace <path> 
                   -scheme <name> 
                   -destination <specifier>
                   -testPlan <name>
                   -skip-test-configuration <configuration1> 
                   -skip-test-configuration <configuration2>
                   ...
```

The relevant lines from the help page:

```
$> xcodebuild -help
Usage: xcodebuild ...
Options:
    -workspace NAME                    build the workspace NAME
    -scheme NAME                       build the scheme NAME
    -destination DESTINATIONSPECIFIER  use the destination described by DESTINATIONSPECIFIER (a comma-separated set of key=value pairs describing the destination to use)
    -testPlan                          specifies the name of the test plan associated with the scheme to use for testing
    -only-test-configuration           constrains testing by specifying test configurations to include, and excluding other test configurations
    -skip-test-configuration           constrains testing by specifying test configurations to exclude, but including other test configurations
    ...
```